# firestore nodejs parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error of parsing error: Unexpected token

I am new to node js and have no idea what this means?

I have looked at various other stack overflow Q&A's but can't find anything that helps.

(I have taken the code straight from the firestore website and changed the values to my own.)

```
exports.sendMessageNotificationFireStore = functions.firestore
.document('/user-messages-notification/{toId}/{fromId}/{message}')
.onWrite((snap, context) => {

  var db = admin.firestore();
  var toId = context.params.toId;  
  var fromId = context.params.fromId;



  console.log('toId is' + toId + 'fromId is' + fromId);

  console.log('toId is' + toId + 'and they recieved a message from fromId  who is' + fromId);


   //start of firestore code
      var cityRef = db.collection('Users').doc(toId);
      var getDoc = cityRef.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              return console.log('No such document!');
            } else {
              return console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            return console.log('Error getting document', err);
          });

  // perform desired operations ...
});//end on firestore code

});
```

Comment: Would you add a link to the firestore website please?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data      thats in the get data section , i am assuming i can use this function inside the onWrite function ( i've just started with nodeJs)

Comment: I don't know JS well enough to say, I'm just triage-ing. Also was there a line number with that error?

Comment: 45:5 . what does that mean? line 45?

Comment: the line just had });

Comment: working now , must have copied and pasted it wrong i'm not sure